# How do I reference the index of an array without knowing what it is in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm making a calendar app where I'm trying to validate if the date entered is during the current semester, and then see if it is a holiday that we don't have class. I have an index of all of the dates that we are out with the names of the respective holidays, but when I tried to use indexOf, the code broke. 
this is the html:

```
<form onsubmit="holiday()" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    Enter Date: <input type='date' id="dat"><p>
    <input class="ubmit" type=submit >
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

this is the js:

```
var dvalue = document.getElementById("dat").value;
function holiday(){
  var txt ="boo";
  dvalue=Date.parse(dvalue);
  console.log(dvalue);
  if (dvalue<1473033600000 || dvalue>1494979200000 || dvalue=="NaN"){
    txt="This is not a valid date for this calendar app";
  }
  else function validate(dvalue){
    var holidayz=new Array();
    holidayz[0]=["Columbus Day",1473033600000];
    holidayz[1]=["Fall Recess",1476057600000];
    holidayz[2]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1479859200000];
    holidayz[3]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1479945600000];
    holidayz[4]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1480032000000];
    holidayz[5]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1480118400000];
    holidayz[6]=["President's Day",1487548800000];
    holidayz[7]=["Spring Recess",1489363200000];
    holidayz[8]=["Spring Recess",1489449600000];
    holidayz[9]=["Spring Recess",1458000000000];
    holidayz[10]=["Spring Recess",1489622400000];
    holidayz[11]=["Spring Recess",1489708800000];
    holidayz[12]=["Reading Day",1494288000000];
    holidayz[13]=["Memorial Day",1496016000000];
    holidayz[14]=["Independence Day",1499126400000];
    if (holidayz.includes(dvalue)){
      var mydate = new Date(dvalue);
      console.log("<p>" + mydate + "<p>");
      var day = mydate.getUTCDate();
      var month = mydate.getMonth()+1;
      var year = mydate.getFullYear();
      console.log (month + "/" + day +"/" + year);
      var holival= asList(holidayz).indexOf(dvalue);
      console.log(holival)
    }
}

  console.log(txt)
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: instead of an array of arrays, why not use an array of objects, which could give you named keys?

Comment: the assignment that I'm doing requires that I use a multidimensional array.

Comment: that seems superfluous, but ok

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var dvalue = document.getElementById("dat").value;

function holiday(){
    var txt ="boo";
    dvalue=Date.parse(dvalue);
    console.log(dvalue);
    if (dvalue<1473033600000 || dvalue>1494979200000 || dvalue=="NaN"){
        txt="This is not a valid date for this calendar app";
    } else {
        var holidayz=new Array();
        holidayz[0]=["Columbus Day",1473033600000];
        holidayz[1]=["Fall Recess",1476057600000];
        holidayz[2]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1479859200000];
        holidayz[3]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1479945600000];
        holidayz[4]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1480032000000];
        holidayz[5]=["Thanksgiving Recess",1480118400000];
        holidayz[6]=["President's Day",1487548800000];
        holidayz[7]=["Spring Recess",1489363200000];
        holidayz[8]=["Spring Recess",1489449600000];
        holidayz[9]=["Spring Recess",1458000000000];
        holidayz[10]=["Spring Recess",1489622400000];
        holidayz[11]=["Spring Recess",1489708800000];
        holidayz[12]=["Reading Day",1494288000000];
        holidayz[13]=["Memorial Day",1496016000000];
        holidayz[14]=["Independence Day",1499126400000];
        holidayz[15]=["Test Day",1476921600000];

        for(var i=0; i<holidayz.length; i++){
            if ((holidayz[i][1])==dvalue){
            var mydate = new Date(dvalue);
            console.log("<p>" + mydate + "<p>");
            var day = mydate.getUTCDate();
            var month = mydate.getMonth()+1;
            var year = mydate.getFullYear();
            console.log (month + "/" + day +"/" + year);
            var holival= i; //asList(holidayz).indexOf(dvalue);
            console.log(holival);
            break;
        }
     }
    }
    console.log(txt);
}
```

[image: Console Output]

Comment: for some reason holival isn't printing in the console.

Comment: @Harmony can you please show us your console output?

Comment: NaN
boo
Navigated to file:///C:/Users/Harmony/Desktop/webdesign/calendar/calendar.html?

Comment: I'm not sure you can see this but hopefully you can this is the link for the assignment. http://i6.cims.nyu.edu/~hrb281/calendar/calendar.html

Comment: @Harmony see the image this is what I got. I think your code is working.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. I changed a few things to make it easier & I stepped back from it but fr some reason nothing is showing up in my console or on the page. jslint says that its syntactically valid. could you check it again?

Comment: @Harmony I think this will work, change your array elements like this. `holidayz[0]=["Columbus Day",Date.parse("2016-09-04")];` 
                `holidayz[1]=["Fall Recess", Date.parse("2016-10-09")];`